# Setting and enabling the speedbar

Tags: speedbar

I am enabling the speedbar using

```
  (speedbar 1)
  (make-face 'speedbar-face)
  (set-face-font 'speedbar-face "Monospace-16")

  (setq speedbar-mode-hook
        '(lambda ()
            (buffer-face-set 'speedbar-face)) )
```

Where does one customarily set `speedbar-add-supported-extension` for the various file extensions?  Before or after enabling speedbar with `(speedbar 1)`?

Also, is it proper to use `set-face-font` after calling `(speedbar 1)`.  Or should the font change be done before enabling the speedbar?